# Error 3078 "cannot find table" in MS Access from external ODBC-linked table

Tags: sql-server-2008, ms-access, vba

Within my Access 2010 form I have the ability to add records, but before one adds a record, we need the ability to check if the business unit, year, and quarter already exists within the SQL table before new record is being written.

The three things I need to confirm are the fields in my form called [BU_Selected_Add], [Qtr_Add] and [Year_Add] in the SQL table "tTbl_ADMIN_RxREBATE" within their respective fields:
[GL_BU], [Year], and [Quarter].
So I started with a simple Business_Unit dlookup below:

```
 If DLookup("[GL_BU]", "tTbl_ADMIN_RxREBATE", "[GL_BU] = '" & 
 Me!BU_Selected_Add & "'") > 0 Then
 MsgBox "This Business Unit already exists within the data below!"
```

I get the following error:

```
Run-time error '3078': The Microsoft Access database engine cannot find the 
input table or query "tTbl_ADMIN_RxRebate".  Make sure it exists and that its 
name is spelled correctly.
```

It most certainly exists in the SQL Server 2008 R2.

I need to get this first part right before adding in whether that [BU_Selected_Add] was added during the year and quarter within the fieldboxes called [Qtr_Add] and [Year_Add].

```
  SELECT dbo_tTbl_ADMIN_RxREBATE.MSID, dbo_tTbl_ADMIN_RxREBATE.DateAdded,      dbo_tTbl_ADMIN_RxREBATE.Qtr, dbo_tTbl_ADMIN_RxREBATE.Year, dbo_tTbl_ADMIN_RxREBATE.Rpt_Date, dbo_tTbl_ADMIN_RxREBATE.SRVC_TYP_CD, dbo_tTbl_ADMIN_RxREBATE.GL_BU, dbo_BU_Description.[BU Description], dbo_tTbl_ADMIN_RxREBATE.PY_FNL_PICK_AMT, dbo_tTbl_ADMIN_RxREBATE.PY_FNL_MRGN_AMT, dbo_tTbl_ADMIN_RxREBATE.PY_IBNR_AMT, dbo_tTbl_ADMIN_RxREBATE.CY_FNL_PICK_AMT, dbo_tTbl_ADMIN_RxREBATE.CY_FNL_MRGN_AMT, dbo_tTbl_ADMIN_RxREBATE.CY_IBNR_AMT
  FROM dbo_tTbl_ADMIN_RxREBATE INNER JOIN dbo_BU_Description ON       dbo_tTbl_ADMIN_RxREBATE.GL_BU = dbo_BU_Description.BU
  WHERE (((dbo_tTbl_ADMIN_RxREBATE.Qtr)=[Forms]![Frm_Main]![Frm_Main_Combo_Qtr]) AND ((dbo_tTbl_ADMIN_RxREBATE.Year)=[Forms]![Frm_Main]![Frm_Main_Combo_Year]));
```

Comment: Can you run a `SELECT` query in Access that is successful for the same purpose?  If so, you will be able to use `DLookup()` ... and you may learn the cause of the problem.

Comment: It sounds like you're saying the Access db includes an ODBC link to a SQL Server table named `tTbl_ADMIN_RxREBATE`.  When I link to SQL Server tables, Access includes the schema name in the link name, replacing the `.` with `_`, so would expect your link to be named something like `dbo_tTbl_ADMIN_RxREBATE`.  I apologize if you've already ruled out this possibility, but it's important because an Access query must use the link name regardless of the actual table name on the server.

Comment: You say "It most certainly exists in the SQL Server 2008...", but you are running the DLookup in Access. Is the SQL Server table linked (ODBC?) to your Access database? <dang! I'm a slow typist!>

Comment: @Hansup that was it, arggh, don't know why I keep forgetting that. Now, how do I layer on Qtr and year to the mix?

Comment: @HansUp, I put the code in Question above.

Comment: @Hansup Correct, The Select Query was from the form and I think that is why I was using the D-Lookup. The Select Query above was derived for the form only, so that we don't create all these one-off views in SQL. Not sure I am making sense. I would probably lean toward a Dlookup.

Comment: I meant a `SELECT` query which returns the same row that you wanted `DLookup` to look at.  Does that make sense?

Comment: @HansUp I would be open to whatever is easiest at this point and not a burden to you. :-)

Comment: If you have your dlookup working you should be able to modify the end to work just like your where statement: `"[GL_BU] = '" & 
 Me!BU_Selected_Add & "' AND [Year] = " & Me![Year_Add] & " AND [Quarter]=" & Me![Quarter_Add]`

Comment: @HansUp I placed the code above as an attempt but it is failing as such: Compile Error: Method or Data Member not found. Wish I was a superstar like you bro.

Comment: Which line causes the compile error?  Is it the line with `qdf.RecordCount`?

Comment: If you just `Debug.Print strRecSetQuery`, then copy the statement text from the Immediate window, paste into SQL View of a new query and run that query ... does the query run without error and return the record (or records?) you expect?

Comment: @HansUp  Perfect, discovered that there was a space missing before the Where!  Woot woot you rock!